# Gradle extend task / Create task based on task

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

New to Groovy, gradle. I want to extend the following task (part of java plugin):

```
jar {
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { zipTree(it) } }

    manifest.attributes( 'Implementation-Title': archivesBaseName,
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': mainClassName,
                'Built-By': POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
    )
}
```

The extended task will have

```
archiveName = 'PJ-latest.jar'
destinationDir = project.getRootDir()
```

In typical Java I would have called `super` but I'm not sure how I can do it in gradle. My best try is to extend the `Jar` class add the same parameters as `jar` has and also the dependencies:

```
task assembleCompiler(type: Jar){
    dependsOn compileJava, processResources, classes

    archiveName = 'PJ-latest.jar'
    destinationDir = project.getRootDir()

    from { configurations.runtime.collect { zipTree(it) } }

    manifest.attributes( 'Implementation-Title': archivesBaseName,
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': mainClassName,
            'Built-By': POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
    )
}
```

Comment: This isn't clear; why can't you put that stuff straight into the `jar` closure?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I want a second task with two different variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to configure the second task separately, like you already did. If you want to share this code, turn it into a plugin.